# Cannot browse asp site from IIS 6.1 from server itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I cannot browse my asp site from IIS 6.1 from server itself .
My deploying steps are

1. I compiled my asp.net web site using [West Wind ASP.NET 2.0 Compiler
   Utility](http://www.west-wind.com/tools/aspnetcompiler.asp)
2. Deploy my web site to `IIS 6.1`
3. Add host header to my host file
   (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) (Let's say :192.168.1.1
   www.mywebsite.com)

I cannot browse `www.mywebsite.com` from my server itself , but I can browse it from client pc by adding host header as step 3 .
I want to know how can i browse my site from server itself . Is there any option ?
Kindly help me , Thanks :)

Comment: Try to ping `www.mywebsite.com` from server - think, this is DNS problem. Also, check IP restrictions in IIS

Comment: When I `ping www.mywebsite.com` > `Request time out !` , how can I check IP restrictions in `IIS 6.1` ?

Comment: Do `ipconfig /all` and ensure, that machine have this IP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this KB... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

If you are able to browse from other machines, and not from local machine, most likely it is due to LoopBackCheck. The KB explains what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

In the server's hosts file, try setting the IP to the loopback address (e.g. 127.0.0.1) instead of the local network IP address.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback  Also double check, how is it bound in IIS?  To a specific IP or to "all addresses"?